# Ping.SendAsyncCancel hangs task

Tags: c#, ping, freeze

I'm using Ping class to ping few hosts periodically. If time for next ping comes, but previous ping was not completed yet, I call SendAsyncCancel to terminate it.

Problem appears if I disable network interface. In this case, asyncronous callback is never called and call to SendAsyncCancel never returns.

Some more info: I'm using .net 3.5 and C# VS2008 express on Windows 7 x64. I call pings from the form's Timer.Tick callback. I create Ping class only once for each host (3 hosts in total, but same with only one host). Timeout is 5 seconds. Problem is 100% repeatable.

All I found is problem with ping crash on multiple create/destroy ping classes, but it is not my case.

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace TestPing {
      public partial class Form1 : Form {

        private Ping Pinger;

         public Form1()
         {
           InitializeComponent();
           Pinger = new Ping();
           Pinger.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);
         }

        private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          txtResult.Text = e.Cancelled ? "Cancelled" : e.Reply.Status.ToString();
        }

        private void butSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          txtResult.Text = "(result)";
          txtStatus.Text = "SendAsync() calling...";
          Pinger.SendAsync(txtHost.Text, null);
          txtStatus.Text = "SendAsync() done.";
        }

        private void butCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          txtStatus.Text = "SendAsyncCancel() calling...";
          Pinger.SendAsyncCancel();
          txtStatus.Text = "SendAsyncCancel() done.";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post same sample code or extract exact code into separate test app, so we can investigate it?

Comment: I created empty project to reproduce and posted its code. Also I noticed that if I use SendAsyncCancel while pinging unexistent host (but network connected), it cancelled only after ping timeout period passes, not immidiately. So probably source of problem is this wait until completion before cancel.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144962(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Pinger.SendAsyncCancel(); seem to not really do this asynchronously. When using .NET 3.5 you can do the following:

```
private void butSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtStatus.Text = "Pinging";
    Pinger.SendAsync(txtHost, null);
}

private void butCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Pinger.SendAsyncCancel);
    t.Start();
}
```

Now, your txtStatus.Text = "Cancel done"; will go here:

```
private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Cancelled)
  {
     txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
     txtStatus.Text = "Cancel done";
  }
  else
  {
     txtResult.Text = e.Reply.Status.ToString();
     txtStatus.Text = "SendAsync done";
  }
}
```

This works like I expect it too on my end.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve original problem. Now program UI not hangs anymore because separate thread hangs instead. SendAsyncCancel never completes, Pinger class becomes unusable (operation still pending) and program never exit because of this thread waiting forever. I wonder why ping waits forever if no network connected, strange behaviour.

Comment: In my test, the textbox displayed "cancelled" a few seconds after I clicked the cancel button. This is the desired result right? Will post it all in a bit.

Comment: @G-Shadow Have a look, and see if your code matches mine.

Comment: I tried your code but problem still exists. Have you tried it with network cable unplugged (or connection disabled)?

Comment: @G-Shadow, yes, with cable in, it says success instantly.

Comment: this helped me in WPF